# Bash: Calling script with multiple optional flags - it always picks the first one and ignores others

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a bash method:

```sh
  SUITE=''
  FILTER=''
  COVERAGE=''
  COVERAGE_REPORT_PATH="tests/Report"

  while getopts :s:f:c: flag # do not remove first colon as it makes flags optional
  do
      case "${flag}" in
          s) SUITE="--testsuite=${OPTARG}";;
          f) FILTER="--filter=${OPTARG}";;
          c) COVERAGE="--coverage-html ${COVERAGE_REPORT_PATH}";;
      esac
  done

  echo "docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit ${SUITE} ${FILTER} ${COVERAGE}";
```

When I run it with: `./local.sh phpunit -s Unit` it prints:

> `docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Unit`

When I run it with: `./local.sh phpunit -f MyClass` it prints:

> `docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit  --filter=MyClass`

But when I run it with both flags: `./local.sh phpunit -s Unit -f MyClass` it only prints the first one:

> `docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Unit`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `do not remove first colon as it makes flags optional` it doesn't, you just lack error handling. I can't reproduce your results - parsing stops at first argument `phpunit` and the `-s` nor `-f` are not parsed at all. This is expected - `getopt` parses arguments _in order_. Is there a `shift` missing in the source you posted?

Comment: unable to reproduce your sample outputs; I **do** get the same output as Cyrus ... none of the flags are processed because the first arg (`phpunit`) is not being processed (and `shift`ed) and hence the flags are never processed; if I remove `phpunit` from the invocation then the script functions as expected (with 1, 2 or 3 flags)

Comment: @KamilCuk:  I believe `getopt` and `getopts` are two different bash commands.  Did you mean to use `getopts` which is what the asker is using?

Comment: @JosephIshak Yes, that's a typo, most probably because I use `getopt` in my scripts :) As for "bash commands" - `getopts` is shell internal special command, `getopt` is a normal external program from `util-linux`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I see on my mac:

```
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh 
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit   
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh phpunit -s Unit
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit   
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh phpunit -s Unit
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit   
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh -s Unit phpunit
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Unit  
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$  ./local.sh phpunit -f MyClass
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit   
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$  ./local.sh -f MyClass
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit  --filter=MyClass 
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh phpunit -s Unit -f MyClass
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit   
IRV-JISHAK-OSX:tmp jishak$ ./local.sh -s Unit -f MyClass
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Unit --filter=MyClass
```

As @markp-fuso points out above, having the `phpunit` argument breaks the parsing as it is being treated as an unhandled option.  I think you can move it to the end or drop it altogether to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For simple options like this, I wouldn't really see a use for `getopts`. Instead what you can do is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SUITE=''
FILTER=''
COVERAGE=''
COVERAGE_REPORT_PATH="tests/Report"

while(($# > 0)); do
    case ${1} in
        -s) shift; SUITE="--testsuite=${1}";;
        -f) shift; FILTER="--filter=${1}";;
        -c) COVERAGE="--coverage-html ${COVERAGE_REPORT_PATH}";;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit ${SUITE} ${FILTER} ${COVERAGE}";
```

And use the `shift` builtin inside a `while` loop to cycle through the arguments until there are none left.

```
./parseopts phpunit -s Unit -f MyClass
```

Outputs

```
docker exec -it my_api_1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Unit --filter=MyClass
```